# Accessing values inside a .sor file

Tags: c#

We have to work on .sor files for a research project. This type of files contains graphical information of distance(m) to loss(dB). I think that .sor files should contain the values of each loss against distance. Is there a way to access these values?

Comment: You can of course access the file contents with `File.ReadAllBytes` or `File.ReadAllText`. The important question is how to parse the file contents. Is it maybe an XML-based file? JSON? Or binary? Since I have never heard of a .sor file and googling it did not turn out anything useful either, it would be useful to have an example of what the contents of such a file look like.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this is OTDR data, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes, it is a OTDR data. I tried to encode it with UTF8 and it looks like this: Map � �   
 GenParams � <   SupParams � :   FxdParams � \   DataPts � �1  KeyEvents � �   WaveMTSParams � �  WavetekTwoMTS � �   WavetekThreeMTS �    ActernaConfig � �  ActernaMiniCurve � Q  JDSUEvenementsMTS � H  Cksum �    GenParams FRLyrtf # �St Etienne  Lyon    CC        JPB   SupParams Acterna MTS 6000  27947 8146 SRL  2403  7.18    FxdParams ���Qkm�<          Zb �  ?< *��  � ��        �������  ST                DataPts �   �  ��r��%iAh8�4�4y6g8,:�<�?�B�FeJ^MzT[`

Comment: Have you made any progress on that? I'm running into the same issue and I definitely don't want to spend $750 just to get the data parsed. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry. I just gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy the SR-4731 document, which describes the Optical Time Domain Reflectometer (OTDR) Data Format, which is used in `.sor` files, for $ 750 [here](http://telecom-info.telcordia.com/site-cgi/ido/docs.cgi?ID=SEARCH&DOCUMENT=SR-4731&#ORD). Gotta love proprietary formats.

Answer (score 0):

Someone made a library and ported it to multiple languages: Python, Perl, Clojure, Nodejs and Ruby.

Here I will link the Python version.
https://github.com/sid5432/pyOTDR
as for C#, I do not know any existing port yet.